# How to write a function (or a macro) to create a Vec and a reference to it?

Tags: macros, rust

So I have something like this:

```
let v = vec![...];
let s = Data { vec: &v, ... };
```

Perhaps this is misguided, but the idea is that many data structures could share the same vector. But for the case where I don't want to share, it would be convenient to have something like this:

```
let (v, s) = make_data(...);
```

Apparently, unlike the first example, there is no way to connect the lifetime of v and s (correct me if I'm wrong). Anyway, I understand the borrow checker rejects this. So I end up doing:

```
let v = vec![];
let s = make_data(&v, ...);
```

Now, perhaps, I could make one of those work:

```
let (v, s) = make_data!(...);
let s = make_data!(v, ...);
let s = make_data!(...);
```

The problem here is that thse macros would expand to something like `{ let v = vec![]; ... }` and `v`'s destructor will be run in the end of this block, but what I really want is to have it expand to something like the first example.

Now, I can make this work:

```
make_data!(v, s, ...);
```

But it's odd. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you want to return a vec and a reference to that vec from the same function? It's trivial to take a reference to that vec after it has been returned.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure I choose the right title. I don't actually want to return `(Vec<T>, &[T])`. The reference is embedded inside a data structure. I can, of course, first create the vector, then create the structure, like shown in the first and third examples -- but in some cases I want to create the two with a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust allows you to define multiple variables with the same name in the same block.

```
let a = vec![...];
let a = Data { vec: &a, ... };
```

On the second line, the new `a` is not in scope yet, so you can still refer to the previous definition of `a`. However, on the following statements, you can no longer refer to the original `a` definition, since the second definition *shadows* the first one; nevertheless, the `Vec` remains alive until the end of the block, as usual.

You can take advantage of this in your macro by only taking a single identifier and using it for both the `Vec` and the slice.

Comment: That's a neat trick, thanks. I ended up moving away from this design, it's simpler to have `Data` own its vector.